# Here-api TransitRadius for intermediate waypoints

Tags: here-api, path-finding

I'm using a following request to calculate a driving route. What is the correct syntax for specifying the transit radius? For some reason the transit radius isn't honoured for the **intermediate** waypoint (waypoint1) while working correctly for the final waypoint.

`https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={appId&app_code={appCode}&waypoint0=geo!50.035035,19.925015;1500&waypoint1=geo!50.06684315082262,19.923276861182046;1500&waypoint2=geo!50.07842990411413,20.032238457351923;1500&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&arrival=2020-05-29T17:27:42.000Z&routeAttributes=shape`

I've done an experiment comparison with and without requesting a transfer radius. It seems to be honoured for start and endpoints only. 
[image]

Comment: @HERE Developer Support would you mind having a look? It seems like a possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

I sent the same request using the routing v7 and authenticated with the APIKEY and I am not getting a loop, but the route leaves the highway, to access the park gate and then comes back onto the highway. I am not able to recreate the loop that you are getting.

Call used

```js
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.16.1&apikey=&waypoint0=50.035035%2C19.925015%3B1500&waypoint1=50.06684315082262%2C19.923276861182046&waypoint2=50.07842990411413%2C20.032238457351923%3B1500&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&arrival=2020-05-29T17%3A27%3A42.000Z&routeAttributes=shape&representation=display
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly the waypoint order is different on the screenshots and in the request. I was testing requests in both directions, to find our what is going on. Anyway the route isn't supposed to leave the main (fastest) road. I specified a transit radius, so is should pass NEXT TO the point specified not leaving the main road. ALSO: It looks like you removed the TransitRadius: ";1500"